# JPEGTranscoder with JCIFS

Tags: java, jcifs

I have referred the following link to convert SVG file to JPEG:

```
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html
```

And following is the sample example I have tried:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;

public class SaveAsJPEG {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a JPEG transcoder
        JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();

        // Set the transcoding hints.
        t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
                   new Float(.8));

        // Create the transcoder input.
        String svgURI = new File(args[0]).toURL().toString();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

        // Create the transcoder output.
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("out.jpg");
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

        // Save the image.
        t.transcode(input, output);

        // Flush and close the stream.
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The above program creates JPEG version of the file in the project path.
Is there any possibility to tweek this program to read and create the converted file in a protected share folder using JCIFS (SmbFile) concept?

Comment: Batik can transcode the file to any output stream, and JCIFS seems to support output streams (see [`SmbFileOutputStream`](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFileOutputStream.html)). Just put an `SmbFileOutputStream` in place of your `FileOutputStream`. It should work. **Disclaimer:** I know Batik, but not JCIFS, this is only after a brief look at its API documentation.